# How to open ppt file using Python

Tags: python

I want to open a ppt file using Python on linux, (like python open a .txt file). 
I know win32com, but I am working on linux. 
So, What do I need to do?

Comment: .ppt files aren't readable as plain text, so you can't really open them "like a .txt file". If you just want to launch the user's default viewer for powerpoint files, you can use the `xdg-open` shell command.

Comment: get the information or words in the file.

Comment: do not ask the same question multiple times; it isn't helpful to anyone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to read ppt file using python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565542/how-to-read-ppt-file-using-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on Linux, what office software are you referring to. OpenOffice (headless) can be interfaced using python on Linux. Here is a nice example https://github.com/jledoux/FRIEDA

Comment: Exactly, I want to get the content in the file. I need the words in it. so, can I get them, like open('a.txt') to get the content in a.txt? thx

Comment: Not so simple. Ppt files are difficult to dissect. The text is contained in individual text elements on each slide. The best way may be to view the file in outline form and extract text via copy and paste.  Or you can try the odf modules discussed below.

Comment: I can use "catdoc"("catppt") to open it with subprocess. and it works.

Answer (score 2):

[python-pptx](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.org) can open recent Powerpoint versions on Linux. They even provide an example for [extracting all text from slides](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/quickstart.html#extract-all-text-from-slides-in-presentation) in their [Getting started](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/quickstart.html) guide.

Here's the code (from the [Getting Started](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/quickstart.html) guide)

```
from pptx import Presentation

prs = Presentation(path_to_presentation)

# text_runs will be populated with a list of strings,
# one for each text run in presentation
text_runs = []

for slide in prs.slides:
    for shape in slide.shapes:
        if not shape.has_textframe:
            continue
        for paragraph in shape.textframe.paragraphs:
            for run in paragraph.runs:
                text_runs.append(run.text)
```

Comment: when using `prs = Presentation(path_to_presentation)` I am getting the following error `File is not a zip file` please help

Comment: @ArunKumar I also get this error, have you found a solution?

Comment: I'm not sure if the code has been updated since this answer, but occurances of `textframe` should be `text_frame`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [odf.opendocument.OpenDocumentPresentation](http://opendocumentfellowship.com/projects/odfpy) from the odfpy project. This is assuming you are only concerned with recent format files, that are compatible with the OpenDocument standard.

If you have access to OpenOffice, you can use their [Python api](http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Python) to read the file.

Answer (score 0):

Using catdoc/catppt with subprocess to open doc files and ppt files.

Answer (score -1):

You may check Apache Tika because I use it on mac like this

For MacOS Homebrew users: install Apache Tika (`brew install tika`)

The command-line interface works like this:

```
tika --text something.ppt > something.txt
```

And to use it inside python script:

```
import os
os.system("tika --text temp.ppt > temp.txt")
```

You will be able to do it and that is the only solution I have so far.