# how to read ppt file using python?

Tags: python

I want to get the content (text only) in a ppt file. How to do it?
(It likes that if I want to get content in a txt file, I just need to open and read. What do I need to do to get information from ppt files?)
By the way, I know there is a win32com in windows system. But now I am working on linux, is there any possible way?

Comment: What do you mean by _content_? text only or diagrams and multimedia as well?

Comment: So, have you tried the unix `strings` on the ppt?

Comment: @mouviciel I just try it. But it does not look good. Some texts are what I want, but some are not.

Comment: @thorstenmüller thx. catdoc is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

I found this discussion over on [Superuser](https://superuser.com/):

[Command line tool in Linux to Extract Text From Word, Excel, Powerpoint?](https://superuser.com/questions/165978/command-line-tool-in-linux-to-extract-text-from-word-excel-powerpoint-or-co)

There are several reasonable answers listed there, including using LibreOffice to do this (and for `.doc`, `.docx`, `.pptx`, etc, etc.), and the [Apache Tika Project](http://tika.apache.org/) (which appears to be the 5,000lb gorilla in this solution space).