# Python 3.6 Extracting text from PPT files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using textract python-pptx to extract the text contents of the files which works well. Unfortunately our client also has ppt files that needs to be processed but we don't have any MS Office/ Open Office in the server so I'm unable to use comtypes to do conversion of the ppt file to another file type and just do the extraction from there.

Greatly appreciate any recommendations of alternative methods.

I'm running Python 3.6 on Windows 64-bit machine.

Comment: My advice would be to install OpenOffice/LibreOffice...

Answer (score 0):

Convert them here. https://convertio.co/ppt-pptx/ This will allow you to use them with your program.

Comment: Sorry I forgot that the environment also cannot connect to the internet as their data contains highly sensitive information

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/24194435/7869371 it looks like the most recent version lets you open ppt files. What error message do you see when trying to open one?

Answer (score -1):

```
    from os.path import isfile, join
    import os
    import re
    from pptx import Presentation

   def getPptContent(path):
      prs = Presentation(path)
    text_runs = []
    for slide in prs.slides:
        for shape in slide.shapes:
            if not shape.has_text_frame:
                continue
            for paragraph in shape.text_frame.paragraphs:
                for run in paragraph.runs:
                   text_runs.append(run.text)
    return text_runs




ppt_dir = "ppt_data"

corpus = [str(f) for f in os.listdir(ppt_dir) if not f.startswith('.') and isfile(join(ppt_dir, f))]

for filename in corpus:
    Path = ppt_dir + "/" +filename
    print(Path)
    file_content = getPptContent(Path)
    f = open(ppt_dir + "/output/" + filename.split(".")[0]  +".txt" ,"w+", encoding="utf-8")
    f.write(str(file_content))
    f.close()
```

Comment: asked for a .ppt solution and not pptx